# В MySQL записи сохраняются неверно

Tags: mysql

В базе MySQL записи сохраняются неверно. Не знаю в кодировке проблема или в чем. В базе вместо некоторых букв (ü,ə,ı,ğ,ö,ş,ç) появляются такие символы É™.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Вместо каких букв?

Comment: Вместо ü,ə,ı,ğ,ö,ş,ç

Comment: А если руками прямо в базу вставлять, то всё ок?

Comment: Да ) Спасибо но уже нашел решение set_charset("utf8");  помогло

Comment: На 5 секунд запоздал с ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что дело в кодировке таблицы. Измените кодировку на UTF-8 и всё будет нормально.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь )

Comment: @fikos, пожалуйста